# How to customize Card.io scannner UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, card.io

In the card.io SDK implementation for Android we launch an CardIOActivity class. Which contains the  camera preview and the "Keyboard" button.

Is it possible to customize the layout of the CardIOActivity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: no.

If you can say a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish, we might be able to figure something out, but in general the layout has been carefully designed to optimize the user experience.

Comment: Thank you Tom, 

Its a requirement from one of our client to have card.io implementation similar to the one that Uber App has.

What would be the best way to take up this discussion with Card.IO team.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to some one if anyone face same issue 
For camera preview use :

EXTRA_SCAN_OVERLAY_LAYOUT_ID
public static final String EXTRA_SCAN_OVERLAY_LAYOUT_ID
Integer extra. Optional. If this value is provided the view will be inflated and will overlay the camera during the scan process. The integer value must be the id of a valid layout resource.

For disabling keyboard button or manual entry:

EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY
public static final String EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY
Boolean extra. Optional. Defaults to false. Removes the keyboard button from the scan screen.

If scanning is unavailable, the Activity result will be RESULT_SCAN_NOT_AVAILABLE.